# dose array_rand() can return all the keys randomized

Tags: php, arrays

As I understand things, the function `array_rand` will pick a random key from an array.
But what if I need to return all the keys randomized?

Here is my code:

```
$answers=array("$q->answer_1", "$q->answer_2", "$q->answer_right");
        $randKey=array_rand($answers,3);
        echo $answers[$randKey[0]]."<br/>";
        echo $answers[$randKey[1]]."<br/>";
        echo $answers[$randKey[2]]."<br/>";
```

So the  number of keys is 3 and I need to return the three keys randomized.
How can I do this?

With my example it does not randomize anything; it just displays

```
"$q->answer_1", "$q->answer_2", "$q->answer_right"
```

the right answer by  kingkero and ben was

```
$answers=array("$q->answer_1", "$q->answer_2", "$q->answer_right");
        $ranKey=shuffle($answers);
        echo $answers[0]."<br />";
        echo $answers[1]."<br />";
        echo $answers[2]."<br />";
```

Comment: What? Why don't you just [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/function.shuffle.php) the original array?

Comment: Note also that if you look at the changelog in the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) for `array_rand`, you'll see that "[t]he resulting array of keys is no longer shuffled" as of version 5.2.10. That's why you're getting the keys back in their original order.

Comment: thanks @kingkero and Ben it worked fine now thanks again and +1 for both.

Comment: @kingkero: Please convert your comment into an answer so it can be upvoted/accepted (and easier for future readers to find it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting one random key at a time, it is much easier to simply order the original array in a random order. PHP offers the function [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/function.shuffle.php) to do this:

```
$answers = shuffle($answers);
foreach ($answers as $answer) {
    echo $answer."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: `shuffle()` returns `true`. Will it not become like doing `foreach(true as true){ echo true."<br>";}`

Answer (score 1):

you write for every random return you 3 item but you're array all 3 items
try this

```
$answers=array("$q->answer_1", "$q->answer_2", "$q->answer_right");
        $randKey=array_rand($answers);
       print_r($randKey);
```

or add more item in array

```
$answers=array("$q->answer_1", "$q->answer_2", "$q->answer_right", '0', '1', '2');
        $randKey=array_rand($answers,3);
        echo $answers[$randKey[0]]."<br/>";
        echo $answers[$randKey[1]]."<br/>";
        echo $answers[$randKey[2]]."<br/>";
```

Comment: of course not it will return `'0', '1', '2'` as results which I don't need and in ex.1 it will return just one key from the array which I don't want too. anyway thanks for the efforts.